# Voting in voter controller for multiple models passing polymorphic/duck typed object variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, polymorphism

I am trying to implement voting for various models: Character, Universe models. I have some vote buttons on their respective show templates via a single DRY rendered partial. This means I need to make that partial agnostic to the model when I pass that model to the controller logic that creates the vote record.

So yes, I am wondering if it is possible to have this kind of duck typed variable passing to a votes controller, rather than repeating the vote creation logic in each of the Character and Universe controller.

How do I make this sort of duck typed variable passing using path helpers, votes partials, and votes controllers? Or should I just repeat the code in each votable model?

FYI: Naturally, the votes is polymorphic to the two models. I am using acts_as_votable gem https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

***_vote.html.haml***

```
.vote-comment-buttons
  = link_to image_tag("upvote.png"), votes_upvote_path(), method: :post, remote: true
  %span=# @comment.get_upvotes.sum(:vote_weight)
  = link_to image_tag("downvote.png"), votes_downvote_path(), method: :post, remote: true
```

^ Do I pass a duck type variable to the paths?, If so, how/where do I define the duck type variable?

(Note: i'm trying to vote via AJAX, but feel free to ignore the ajax related code like remote: true)

**character.rb**

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable # creates a polymorphic association with votes
end
```

**universe.rb**

```
class Universe < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable # creates a polymorphic association with votes
end
```

**votes_controller.rb**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :check_if_voted(@votable)

  def upvote
    #votable.vote_up current_user

  end

  def downvote(votable)
    #votable.vote_down current_user
  end
end
```

Iis it valid to have parameters on actions? or do you just use params[]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Iis it valid to have parameters on actions? or do you just use
>   params[]?

You can not have parameters at public actions, all the data should be parsed from params[]

> How do I make this sort of duck typed variable passing using path
>   helpers, votes partials, and votes controllers? Or should I just
>   repeat the code in each votable model?

Assuming voting procedure is the same for both models, consider using [concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html):

**config/application.rb**

```
 module YourApplicationName
   class Application < Rails::Application
     config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns)
   end
 end
```

**app/controllers/concerns/voting_controller.rb**

```
module VotingController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :obtain_resources, only: [:upvote, :downvote]
  end

  def upvote
    # here goes your upvoting logics, something like
    # @object.liked_by user1, :vote_weight => 1
    # the @object variable has already been set in obtain_resource filter
    # other params should be catched up from the params hash
  end

  def downvote
    # here goes your downvoting logics
  end

  private
  def obtain_resources
    # here we retrieve the name of a particular controller which triggered this action
    model = controller_name.singularize.camelize.constantize
    @object = model.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

In case you prefer using meaningful variable names instead of just `@object`, you can do this kind of thing:

```
# app/controllers/concerns/voting_controller.rb
def obtain_resources
  model = controller_name.singularize.camelize.constantize
  instance_name = controller_name.singularize
  # here you get @universe or @character
  instance_variable_set "@#{instance_name}", model.find(params[:id])
end
```

Then in your controllers you should include that concern:

```
class UniverseController < ApplicationController
  include VotingController
  # that's all, you should not implement voting actions here as they are included from VotingController
end

class CharactersController < ApplicationController
  include VotingController
end
```

You should also be sure to set appropriate routes in your **config/routes.rb** file, so that `upvote` and `downvote` actions exist in **both** of the controllers. As you could already understand, you should pass `upvote_universe_path` or `upvote_characters_path` to your partial to make this work (same for the downvoting). Each route should pass `id` of the object to controller's action.

Comment: Question: I am using the acts_as_votable gem, and it has its own controller, migrations in the gem files. While I see the beauty of using a module controller, it would be redundant to create a second controller, and possibly create issues getting things to function.

Comment: Well, there are lots of threads and resources discussing how to learn rails the best way (just check it in google). As of personal recommendations, take a look at https://www.codeschool.com/. They got plenty of beginner- and intermediate-level courses on ruby/rails.

Comment: Are u sure about controller actions inside of ``acts_of_votable`` gem? As far as I see from [documentation](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) and source code, it only appends some methods to your models, so the controller part should be done individually.

Comment: I've got good conceptual knowledge and can break down what pieces need to be filled. But syntactical knowledge and experience is holding me back. I feel like I'm ready for intermediate to advanced stuff, as long as there is good documentation, or if I get accelerated ability to read source code better. I'll check out the controller thing. I've learned so much so quickly from your example already. Controller concerns, getting things as strings from various rails locations like controllers...

Comment: The table name is votes rather than voting. Should the controller be named votescontroller or should it be named votingscontroller to avoid any clashing, or does it not matter, since it is not restful? How can I tell?

Comment: Well, concern is not a controller, it's just a module which methods are used somewhere else (mostly in many places at once). As concern is not mentioned in routes and not linked with any of your models directly, you can choose whatever name you like. The only requirement is being self-explanatory for people who read your actual controller classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55518/discussion-between-twonegatives-and-gwho).

Comment: I missed your chat invite. I had to sleep for a bit. I also needed some time to try it and play with it. One thing i ran into was the index action throwing a `Couldn't find Universe without an ID` error, which was solved by `before_action :obtain_resources, only: [:show]`

Comment: the fact that my vote buttons are a partial rendered into different models' show actions means the `upvote_model_path` needs to be dynamic as well. I'm trying `upvote_"#{votable_name}"_path`, where `votable_name` is a public getter method... except in the a model concern... Making strings as portions of method names is something very useful that I am continually running into trouble with in various other aspects as well. But we can talk in chat as well.

Comment: did you mean `instance_variable_names()` instead of `instance_variable_set`? that isn't defined anywhere in our code, nor is it in the rails api.

Comment: I believe loadpaths for concerns are automatic in rails 4, making `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/controllers/concerns)` redundant.

Comment: @gwho `instance_variable_set` is a method of `Object`. should work for both Ruby 1.9 and 2.1. Have a look at [this api page](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set).